# My SKAction does not work Swift sprite kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to do this for a long time. My problem is when I make a `moveTo` action, 
it comes up with an error saying 
"**'playscene -> () -> PlayScene does not have a member named 'frame'**"

Here is my code:

```
let actionmove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.frame)), duration:0.5)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the line of code was not in one of the functions so it was in the class but **not** in the one of the functions such as didmovetoview or touchesBegan.